# Adding two numbers using a randomised operator

Tags: python, math, random

The following is my code, and it works. It creates two random numbers, a random operator and puts them together, however it does not sum them after doing this. What I need is for the program to recognise it as an equation, rather than simply printing out the individual variables.

So, to avoid confusion; my question is: How would I get `firstNumber` and `secondNumber`to be summed together using whatever `operator` is selected, rather than simply printing them out together?

```
from random import choice
from random import randint

ranOperator = ["*", "/", "+", "-"]

def askQuestion():
    firstNumber = randint(1,10)
    secondNumber = randint(1,10)
    operator = choice(ranOperator)

    generateQuestion = ' '.join((str(firstNumber), operator, str(secondNumber)))
    print(generateQuestion)

askQuestion()
```

Current output (example):

```
4 + 3
```

Using the same numbers above, what I would want to happen:

```
7
```

Comment: Can you update the question to give an example of both the current output and the desired output?

Comment: Simple way is `eval()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 7):

One way to not rely on `eval` is using the `operator` module to represent the operations.

```
from random import choice
from random import randint
from operator import add, sub, truediv, mul

ranOperator = [add, sub, truediv, mul]

def askQuestion():
    firstNumber = randint(1,10)
    secondNumber = randint(1,10)
    the_operator = choice(ranOperator)

    result = the_operator(firstNumber, secondNumber)
    print(result)
```

Comment: plus 1 since it more safe

Answer (score 3):

What you need is `eval()`.

`eval()` **evaluates** the passed string as a Python expression and returns the result.

```
from random import choice
from random import randint

ranOperator = ["*", "/", "+", "-"]

def askQuestion():
    firstNumber = randint(1,10)
    secondNumber = randint(1,10)
    operator = choice(ranOperator)

    generateQuestion = ' '.join((str(firstNumber), operator, str(secondNumber)))
    print(eval(generateQuestion))

askQuestion()
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> eval('1+1')
2
>>> eval('5-3')
2
>>> eval('2*3')
6
>>> eval('6/3')
2
```

Comment: Just adding that eval can be dangerous - https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: Fortunately in this case all the inputs to `eval` are controlled by the program. (Still, not an excuse to use eval when the `operator` module is available)

Comment: @quamrana @Matt. Stroh In this context, it does not matter if you use `eval` - not dangerous as you say. After all, we want our work to be done. If it can be done (safe here), why bother about danger!

Comment: @theausome Unfortunately its not about *this* case, its about the case in the future where the program is 'extended' and includes uncontrolled input.

Answer (score 3):

Extending dseuss's answer to incorporate any function and print a math-like equation by mapping a function to its symbol using a dictionary

```
from random import choice
from random import randint

add = lambda x,y: x+y
substract = lambda x,y: x-y
divide = lambda x,y: x/y
multiply = lambda x,y: x*y

ranOperator = {"*":multiply, "/":divide, "+":add, "-":substract}

def askQuestion():
    firstNumber = randint(1,10)
    secondNumber = randint(1,10)
    operator_key = choice(list(ranOperator.keys()))

    answer = ranOperator[operator_key](firstNumber,secondNumber)
    print("{} {} {} = {}".format(firstNumber, operator_key, secondNumber, answer))

askQuestion()
```